# ElephantSQL and Django not working together, atuhentication failed

Tags: django, postgresql

I have bumped into the following problem and still don't know how to fix it. For the record I am using mac.

I would like to connect my djnago app to an elephantsql database, so I have changed the database info.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'abc',
    'USER':'abc',
    'PASSWORD':'password', 
    'HOSTS':'tai.db.elephantsql.com',
    'PORT': 5432
    }
```

}

I see my database working fine in pgAdmin 4, so there is no issue with that, but when I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

got the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "abc"
```

Do you have any tips how to go forward?

Comment: It is `'HOST'`, not `'HOSTS'`.

Answer (score 2):

You specify the host of the database with the `HOST` key, not the <s>`HOSTS`</s> for the [**`DATAbASES`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases):

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'abc',
    'USER': 'abc',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    # ↓ HOST instead of HOSTS
    'HOST': 'tai.db.elephantsql.com',
    'PORT': 5432
  }
}
```