# ElephantSQl configurations for Django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web-deployment, vercel

I'm trying to have a DJANGO project on VERCEL which wouldn't let me use sqlite3, so I decided to use the ElephantSQL for my project and I created an account and have the URL but I don't have any idea how to do the configurations for DJANGO . I've searched all around YOUTUBE and StackOverFlow but didn't find anything helpful. can anyone PLEASE help me with this ? where should I start from ?

Update :

I changed DATABASES in settings.py to this :

```
DATABASES = {
    
     'default': {

         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

         'NAME': 'my_User',

         'USER': 'my_User',

         'PASSWORD': 'my_Password',

         'HOST': 'heffalump.db.elephantsql.com',

         'PORT': '5432',

     }
}
```

based on my URL which is : postgres://my_User:my_Password@heffalump.db.elephantsql.com/my_User
and then tried python manage.py makemigrations but then got this error :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "heffalump.db.elephantsql.com" to address: Host name lookup failure
```

NOTE: I'm currently in Iran and internet limitations may affect my connection.

Comment: Here [Django connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720355/cannot-connect-elephantsql-database-to-django), [Django db settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases) and here [Django connect #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68753685/elephantsql-and-django-not-working-together-atuhentication-failed) as starters.

Comment: Since the host name lookup fails - verify that it is correct, and check if you're able to resolve it with `nslookup` or `host` in your operating system. Since your internet might be limited, it's hard for anyone that isn't under the same limitations to verify it for you. The host does resolve for me, at least.

Comment: 1) Can you connect via the ElephantSQL interface? 2) Is `ping heffalump.db.elephantsql.com` successful?

Comment: @MatsLindh this is nslookup response for host address : UnKnown can't find heffalump.db.elephantsql.com: Server failed

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ping heffalump.db.elephantsql.com responsed :(Ping request could not find host heffalump.db.elephantsql.com. Please check the name and try again.) , and No i can't have its interface but in some cases i was able to reach a banned service from terminal

Comment: Then I think it  is safe to say it is being blocked.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver so isn't there anything wrong with the written address?? is it ok and  i'm gonna be ok with free internet you guess?

Comment: On my end(USA): `ping heffalump.db.elephantsql.com PING ec2-50-18-63-64.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (50.18.63.64) 56(84) bytes of data. ...`. So it is a valid address. Not sure what you mean by "... i'm gonna be ok with free internet you guess?"? Can you create a local instance of Postgres to work with?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver so it's 100% my internet . i thought maybe something is wrong with my codes or commands so i asked that to be sure . thank you so much for your help and time

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i tried to makemigration from vercel so i changed setting.py and added migration commands in build_files.sh in my github repo ,now i get (pg_config executable not found.) from vercel's log do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry i didn't see your last qs. i can use postgres locally but not on vercel it's not letting users have database directly on it as far as i found out